# How to render a custom view in a NPM module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

Since `pushAsset` does not allow to load external resources, I want to render this template/script of my NPM module:

views/tag.html

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{ data.gid }}"></script>
```

NPM modules are kind of different to project level modules, because I cannot directly edit the project files.

Comment: When / how are you trying to render this tag template? What is the desired flow to get this template in the browser?

Comment: This template should render on every page request. This tag should be always at the start of the `head`.

Comment: You should be able to just `{% include 'tag.html' %}` right in your block tag, assuming your tag.html lives in `lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/views/tag.html` or its fallback equivalent. If its an individual module you would `{% include 'my-module:tag.html' %}`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that this relates to NPM modules. Updated the question and answered it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apostrophe provides [helper functions for Nunjucks](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/nunjucks-filters.html#apostrophe-also-adds-helper-functions). Some of them – like [addAfterContextMenu](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.html#add-after-context-menu) – can be used as hooks to insert templates of NPM modules into other templates.

These *hooks* are declared inside `apos.pages`. Usage:

```
self.apos.pages.startHead(function(req) {
  return self.partial('templateName', { gid: 'UA-123456-1' });
});
```

`startHead` could be a hook that inserts the `partial` inside the `startHead` block of `outerLayoutBase`. Currently, Apostrophe does not provide many hooks for NPM module authors. But this is [subject to change](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/pull/1456).